# How to retrieve access in Javascript using Global Variable?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, access

I read here that we can access ObjectType from Global Variable.I want to check if the user able to edit Account using updateable .But how to write it?

I tried this

```
  {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/30.0/connection.js")}
    console.log('@Test  ==='+{!$ObjectType.Account.updateable});
```

It throw me this error.

> Error: Field updateable does not exist. Check spelling.

So I copy paste this just to test

```
{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.Label}
```

Also it throw me error.

> Error: Field Account.fields.Name.Label does not exist. Check spelling.

What is the correct way to use Global Variable in Javascript?

Comment: Lightning, Visualforce, static resource?

Comment: @sfdcfox for object custom button javascript

Answer (score 1):

To know whether user can edit the record you can Query `UserRecordAccess` object. You will get all the details as below.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js")}

var result = sforce.connection.query("SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasEditAccess, HasDeleteAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = '{!$User.Id}' AND RecordId = '{!Account.Id}'", {onSuccess : success, onFailure : failure});
function success(result) {
    var records = result.getArray("records");
    if(records[0]){
        var accessdetail = records[0];
        console.log("HasDeleteAccess = "+accessdetail.HasDeleteAccess);
        console.log("HasEditAccess = "+accessdetail.HasEditAccess);
        console.log("HasReadAccess = " + accessdetail.HasReadAccess);
    }
}
function failure(error) {
    console.log("An error has occurred " + error);
}
```

Comment: can we use Global variable instead of query?